# Permissions required to read from /dev/hidraw0

Tags: android

Is there any permissions tag to request access to `/dev/hidraw` devices? ADB shows it is owned by `radio:radio`

```
./adb shell ls -l /dev/hidraw0
```

`crw------- radio radio    251,   0 2011-07-25 18:33 hidraw0`

```
FileReader input = new FileReader("/dev/hidraw0"); throws a FileNotFoundException
```

`"/dev/hidraw0 (Permission denied)"`

I am using Android version 3.2 on a Motorola Xoom wi-fi tablet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, that's absolutely not allowed to applications.

Comment: What about my system service or daemon? what permissions would it need?